# Android FTPClient connection to local host

Tags: android, localhost, ftp-client

how to connect to local host from android ftp client with emulator? What ip and port number should used in method "connect(host,port)"? When I tried with 10.0.2.2,127.0.0.1 with port number 21 the connection is refused. I am using Ubuntu with eclipse.
please help...

Answer (score 0):

you should use Asynctask like this code :

```
@Override
```

protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
     //activity is defined as a global variable in your AsyncTask

    try {

        HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet hg = new HttpGet(params[0]);
        HttpResponse hr = hc.execute(hg);
        HttpEntity he = hr.getEntity();
        data = EntityUtils.toString(he);
        Log.i("data", data);

    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





}
```

and then when you use it like this :

```
 new asy().execute("http:// put your ip address here ");
```